# MESSAGE=anthony ... USER=root <-- Does this mean that the root user is the actual user but "anthony" will be displayed as being the user anyway?

Tags: ubuntu, security, logs, users

I found this in /run/log/journal/...

```
MESSAGE=anthony : TTY=pts/10 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/find / -name *systemctI*
```

I'm wondering what this means? I'm suspicious of this process "`systemctI`" since it's one letter off from `systemctl`. And I was doing some digging and found the above in a log file.

What does it mean? I have a feeling it means the process is using the root user but is pretending to use "anthony." Is this correct?

Comment: The real systemctl ends with an L, but the one in my logs ends with an capital i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax matches log messages generated by `sudo`, but if you are viewing it from `systemd`'s journal files, then it might not have the normal syslog-style `<timestamp> <hostname> <program name>:` prefix.

The journal files are in a binary format, so they're best viewed using the `journalctl` command or some other `systemd`-specific viewer. If you just look for text among the binary data, you'll miss the timestamps and other important metadata.

Assuming this is in fact generated by `sudo`, it would mean that user `anthony` had a session running on a pseudo-TTY `pts/10` (= might be a terminal window in a local GUI session, or e.g. a remote SSH session), `cd`'d to the root directory, and ran a command `sudo find / -name *systemctI*`.

`last anthony | grep pts/10` might give you more information on whether the session was a local terminal window or a remote session, and when the session might have happened. If the 3rd field of the `last` output says `:0`, then that is a local X11 GUI session; otherwise it should have the source IP address of the remote session.